# The equivalent axiom of closure operator on a partial order set

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$ A function $\cl: P → P$ from a partial order $P$ to itself is called a closure operator if it satisfies the following axioms for all elements $x, y$ in $P$,

(a) $x ≤ \cl(x)$
($\cl$ is extensive)

(b)$x ≤ y$ implies $\cl(x) ≤ \cl(y)$  ($\cl $ is increasing)

(c)$\cl(\cl(x)) = \cl(x)$($\cl$ is idempotent)

More succinct alternatives are available: the definition above is equivalent to the single axiom

> $x ≤ \cl(y)$ if and only if $\cl(x) ≤ \cl(y)$
>   for all $x, y$ in $P$.

---

The above is a copy of Wikipedia, I want to prove the equivalence.

Suppose we have the single axiom.

(a) Since $\cl(x)\leq \cl(x)$, $ x\leq\cl(x)$;

(b) If $x\leq y$, then $x\leq\cl(y)$ by (a), thus $\cl(x)\leq\cl(y)$;

(c) From (a) and (b), we know that $\cl(x)\leq\cl(\cl(x))$.

**My Question**:

> How to verify $\cl(\cl(x))\leq \cl(x)$?

Comment: Elements of the form $cl\; x$ are known as *closed elements*, so the final single axiom says $x$ is contained in a closed element $y' := cl', y$ precicely when the closure of $x$ is also contained in $y'$; i.e., the closure of $x$ is the least *closed* element containing $x$ ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}\cl(\cl(z))\le \cl(z)$ iff $\cl(z)\le \cl(z)$ (why?)

> Take $x=\cl z$ and $y=z$.

Comment: Oh, how can it be so simple!